# BEP-20 Token transfer error( unable to locate corresponding transfer event log)

Tags: solidity

Please while trying to transfer coin the transaction status said *fail* when I checked on the blockchain I saw an error stating that

```
BEP-20 Token transfer error( unable to locate corresponding transfer event log)
```

I tried transferring coin

Answer (score 0):

Error message suggests that the transaction failed due to problem with the transfer event log associated with BEP-20 token.

- Double check the recipient address, even a small mistake in the address can result in failed transaction
- verify that you have enough funds in your wallet to cover the transaction, including any gas fees required for transfer
- if the blockchain network you are using is congested, it can cause delays or failures in transaction. Check the network status